# How to tell if library supports autolinking?

Tags: react-native

I have to use this library for react native: [@ihealth/ihealthlibrary-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ihealth/ihealthlibrary-react-native)

Nothing indicates in the docs that it supports autolinking.

I was wondering how can you tell if this is supported by looking at the source code ?